# GridView and SqlDataSource

Tags: c#, .net, database

Im trying to create my own command to extract data.
First im make in .aspx from toolbox SqlDataSource :

```
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        onselecting="SqlDataSource2_Selecting"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Then add GridView:

```
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        onselecting="SqlDataSource1_Selecting"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

and now I want to write my own query so I doubleclick on "SqlDataSource" >go into .aspx.cs:

```
protected void SqlDataSource1_Selecting(object sender, SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)    
{
    SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT name, num  FROM Table WHERE T_Name=@MyString";
}
```

Where is the problem ? When I run this app is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems. 
First one is you have used a parameterized query but haven't define what your parameter is.
Second one is you just assign an SQL query to your SqlDataSource1 but you haven't say that to do with that.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Data.Sql.SqlConnection conn= new System.Data.Sql.SqlConnection(/*your connection string comes here*/);

    string query= "SELECT name, num  FROM Table WHERE T_Name=@MyString";

    System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
    System.Data.Sql.SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.Sql.SqlCommand(query, conn);

    System.Data.Sql.SqlDataAdapter da1 = new System.Data.Sql.SqlDataAdapter(cmd );
    da1.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MyString", your_string);

    da1.Fill(dt);

        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

Comment: i trying do like this and  error: 
"Data properties on data control 'GridView1' such as DataSource, DataSourceID, and DataMember cannot be changed during the databinding phase of the control." in "GridView1.DataSource = dt;"

Answer (score 0):

you didn't set the parameters for `SqlDataSource1`.

and i cant the connection string.

Answer (score 0):

You should add select parameters with the select command

```
protected void SqlDataSource1_Selecting(object sender, SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
        {
            SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT name, num  FROM Table WHERE T_Name=@MyString";
SelectParameters["MyString"].DefaultValue = "Your Parameter here";

        }
```